# how to convert firefox jetpack extension -> to firefox addon sdk extension

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using Add-on Builder Beta  (Firefox) and I'm trying to do something like this:

(There are 3 sections in Addon Builder: Lib, Data, Libraries)

1. Get "def.htm" file from data section and open it in new tab
   I do it with this:

   ```
   var tabs = require("tabs");
   var data = require("self").data;
   tabs.open(data.url('def.htm'));
   ```
2. Get the JSON definition from "def.htm"
   def.htm looks like this:

   ```
   <html><head>
   <title>Def title</title>
   </head><body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       this.definition = {
           aaa: 1000,
           bbb: {
               ccc: {
                   ddd: "eee",
                   ...
                   ...
      };
   </script>
   </body></html>
   ```
3. Call JS function and pass the definition to it:

It works with the Jetpack extension (on Firefox 3.5), here is the code:

```
jetpack.tabs.onReady(function() {
    var window = this.contentWindow.wrappedJSObject;
    var def = window.definition;

    dowork (def); 
});
```

I need the same functionality on Add-on SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a rather strange approach, why are you trying to get JSON data in such a complicated way? How about putting it into a file `data/definition.json` (properly encoded then):

```js
{
    "aaa": 1000,
    "bbb": {
        "ccc": {
            "ddd": "eee",
            ...
            ...
};
```

And reading it out using the [`request` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html):

```js
var Request = require("request").Request;
var data = require("self").data;
Request({
  url: data.url("definitions.json"),
  onComplete: function(response)
  {
    dowork(response.json);
  }
});
```

But if you really want to access data in a tab - the Add-on SDK doesn't allow direct access to content pages from your extension. You can use the [`page-mod` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) to inject a content script into this page that will then send the data back to the extension. Something along these lines:

```js
var PageMod = require("page-mod").PageMod;
PageMod({
  include: data.url("def.htm"),
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScript: 'self.postMessage(definition)',
  onAttach: function onAttach(worker)
  {
    worker.on("message", function(data)
    {
      dowork(data);
    });
  }
});
```